# How to cluster *features* based on their correlations to each other with sklearn k-means clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with rows as records (patients) and 105 columns as features.(properties of each patient)

I would like to cluster, not the patients, not the rows as is customary, but the columns so I can see which features are similar or correlated to which other features. I can already calculate the correlation each feature with every other feature using `df.corr()`. But how can I cluster these into k=2,3,4... groups using `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`?

I tried `KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(df.T)` which does cluster the features (because I took the transpose of the matrix) but only with a Euclidian distance function, not according to their correlations. I prefer to cluster the features according to correlations.

This should be very easy but I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What happens if some feature A is correlated to B and B is correlated to C but A is not correlated to C? This situation can arise easily. If you have two clusters (roughly speaking, the group of correlated features and the group of not correlated features), then A and C belong to the same group (not correlated features) but A and B belong to the other group (correlated features). How would you handle that? There can't be intersection between your groups.

Comment: It may be a bit stupid but what about the PCA ? If multiples features are correlated, their respectives eigenvectors provided by the decomposition of the Covariance matrix should be "close" right ? You can after perform a clustering by using cosine similarity ?

Answer (score 2):

KMeans is not very useful in this case, but you can use any clustering method that can work with distances matrix. For example - agglomerative clustering.

I'll use scipy, sklearn version is simpler, but not such powerful (e.g. in sklearn you cannot use WARD method with distances matrix).

```py
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd

df = ...  # your dataframe with many features
corr = df.corr()  # we can consider this as affinity matrix
distances = 1 - corr.abs().values  # pairwise distnces

distArray = ssd.squareform(distances)  # scipy converts matrix to 1d array
hier = hierarchy.linkage(distArray, method="ward")  # you can use other methods
```

Read docs to understand `hier` structure.

You can print dendrogram with

```py
dend = hierarchy.dendrogram(hier, truncate_mode="level", p=30, color_threshold=1.5)
```

And finally, obtain cluster labels for your features

```py
threshold = 1.5  # choose threshold using dendrogram or any other method (e.g. quantile or desired number of features)

cluster_labels = hierarchy.fcluster(hier, threshold, criterion="distance")
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new matrix by taking the correlations of all the features `df.corr()`, now use this new matrix as your dataset for the k-means algorithm.
This will give you clusters of features which have similar correlations.